# xlrd cell value returns error

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I have  a spreadsheet with the below structure (Data starts from Column B. Col A is empty)

```
A   B         C            D
    Name      city        salary
    Jennifer   Boston      100
    Andrew     Pittsburgh  1000 
    Sarah      LA          100
    Grand Total            1200
```

I need to filter out the row with the grand total before loading it into the database.

For this, I'm reading the Grand Total as:

```
import xlrd
import pymssql

#open workbook
book = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\_Workspace\Test\MM.xls")
print( "The number of worksheets is", book.nsheets) 

#for each row in xls file loop
#skip last row 
last_row = curr_sheet.nrows
print(last_row)
print(curr_sheet.ncols)
skip_val = curr_sheet.cell(last_row,1).value
print( skip_val)

if skip_val == "Grand Total":
last_row = last_row - 1
else:
last_row = last_row

 for rx in range(last_row):
print( curr_sheet.row(rx))
```

However, I'm getting the below error:

> ```
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>        File "C:\_Workspace\Test\xldb.py", line 26, in <module>
>        skip_val = curr_sheet.cell(last_row,1).value
>         File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.3-     >py3.4.egg\xlrd\sheet.py",    line 399, in cell
>         self._cell_types[rowx][colx],
>         IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

I'm not able to figure out what is wrong with the syntax above. Hoping someone here can spot why its throwing the error.

Thanks much in advance,
Bee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is not accounting for the zero-based index.  `last_row = curr_sheet.nrows` returns the number of rows in the worksheet, so accessing the last row requires:

```
skip_val = curr_sheet.cell_value(last_row-1, 1)
```

The first element in Python is indexed by 0, so the first element of a list `mylist` would be `mylist[0]`. The last element is not `mylist[len(mylist)]`, instead it's `mylist[len(mylist)-1]`, which should be written as `mylist[-1]`. You can therefore write the following:

```
skip_val = curr_sheet.cell_value(-1, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you @ChrisP . This was the issue. Works like a charm now.